# left and right hand limits

Tags: calculus, limits

I have this limit: $$ \lim_{x\to2}\frac{x^2}{2x-4}$$ and I know (by looking at Wolfram Alpha) that this function does not have a limit, but it has left and right hand limits. Firstly, how do I determine that the limit does not exists? And second, how do I calculate the left and right hand limits?

Answer (score 9):

To begin, note that the limit will exist if and only if the left hand and right hand limits both exist *and* agree with each other.

Let us think informally about the behavior of the function as $x \rightarrow 2$ from either side.  Approaching from the right, we see the numerator is approaching $4$ whereas the denominator is approaching $0$ (think: getting arbitrarily small).  At the same time, the whole fraction is always positive.  So what is $\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow 2^+} \frac{x^2}{2x - 4}$?

If we instead approach from the left, once again the numerator approaches $4$ and the denominator approaches $0$.  *However*, this time the fraction is always negative since $2x - 4 < 0$ when $x < 2$.  So what is $\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow 2^-} \frac{x^2}{2x - 4}$?

If you're feeling shaky with the above reasoning, I encourage you to plug, say, $x = 1.9$ and $x = 1.99$ into the fraction to get a more concrete sense of what is happening when approaching from the left, and likewise $x = 2.1$ and $x = 2.01$ when approaching from the right. If desired, **there is no shame in doing this sort of experimentation**.  Once you have the basic intuition, you can add as much rigor as you'd like with an epsilon-delta type argument.

Comment: Ok, so by that I know that the right hand side limit would be positive and the left hand side negative. But there will still be division by zero if I should try to calculate either of them, right?

Comment: Yes, there will still be division by zero. There is a vertical asymptote at $x=2$, so the limits will be respectively $\infty$ and $-\infty$.

Comment: Yes I know, but how do I calculate it?

Comment: @theva, what happens when you try to divide a numerator close to $4$ by a denominator that's getting smaller and smaller?  I.e. we'd have $\frac{4}{.01}$, and then later on $\frac{4}{.000001}$, and so forth.

Comment: Oh, I see, the value goes towards $\infty$!

Comment: @theva, there you go!

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=2+h$, so that when $x\to2$, $h\to0$
$$\lim_{x\to2^+}\frac{x^2}{2x-4}=\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{4+h^2+4h}{2h}=\lim_{h\to0^+}\left(\frac2h+\frac h2+2\right)=\infty$$
$$\lim_{x\to2^-}\frac{x^2}{2x-4}=\lim_{h\to0^-}\frac{4+h^2+4h}{2h}=\lim_{h\to0^-}\left(\frac2h+\frac h2+2\right)=-\infty$$